# Read YouTube XML with SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml, youtube-api

I want to read/retrieve some details from a single YouTube video using:

```
$sxml= simplexml_load_file("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ");
```

How can i read the tags from the XML file like title, description? I search and found a couple of tutorials, but I can't find one that shows how to read specific XML data. Any good tutorial links or examples will be appreciated.

Comment: *Try*, young grasshopper. If at first you do not succeed... Try, try again.

Comment: @Olli, that actually worked `echo $sxml->title;echo "</br>";echo $sxml->content;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp
Basic use would be

```
print $xml->something;
```

Comment: Ooph. Generally, linking to some off-site tutorial as an answer is frowned upon (since the answer is not *here* per se, and that link may go dark at some point). Secondly, linking to w3schools on SO is generally discouraged as well, see http://w3fools.com. Double whammy. You may get downvotes. `:(`

Comment: Actually there is not much SimpleXML guides @ SO, and I read that w3schools guide and it was quite ok.

Comment: No, there's the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).